# Import n'th data from a file and do calculation on it

Tags: import

I want to import a n'th data from a data file and then do some calculation on it. 
Here is may sample code:

```
ss = Import["myfile.data", {"Words", 3}]
gg = ss + 1
```

And its out put:

```
0.73
1 + "0.73"
```

It doesn't evaluate 1+0.73

Comment: try `Import["myfile.data", "Table"][[3, 1]]`

Comment: Dear george2079, it was a better solution. Because some number in my data file is like "0.72e2" and by your solution I can do calculation on such data conveniently. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

You've `Import`ed as `"Words"`, which returns strings. You can use `ToExpression` to convert them (if you trust the input not to contain malicious input), or `ImportString["123.5", "Real32"]`. Alternatively you may look up `SemanticImport` instead of `Import`, or exploiting more of the structure of the data file, you could use something that is not `"Words"`.

Comment: Thanks a billion dear Patrick. You solved my frustrating problem.       Good luck